# @username disappears in comments

Tags: support, comments

When writing a comment that starts with `@username`, such prefix will disappear.
For example, this:

```
@Name My comment.
```

Will look like:

```
My comment.
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

> The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of any new comment. There is no need to use *@name* to notify them. (You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the author have been commenting on the post so far, the *@name* will be [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099) from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value.)

Comment: I disagree with that it adds no value. Sometimes I want to make it clear that I'm responding to a comment and not to the post itself, in which case it's useful for clarity, even though it doesn't change who gets notified. If a user writes it, there is a reason, so it shouldn't be removed. A workaround that I found was adding a zero-width space between the `@` and the name, but it's annoying to have to do that.

Comment: Perhaps SO could consider a very brief notification on screen to the effect of "question/answer authors will automatically be notified" - this could save people thinking the site (or their browser) is broken and looking up this meta question.