# @ mention at beginning of comment

Tags: support

Often in comments I want to @ mention a user at the beginning of the comment.

For example:

> @foo could you please clarify what you mean by bar?

But I find that although I'm able to write my comment in the form the comment actually gets rendered as:

> could you please clarify what you mean by bar?

Why is this? How do I @ mention at the beginning of the comment?

Comment: The commenting system sometimes detects usages of `@username` that are redundant because the notification will go to that user anyway and there's no ambiguity as to who you're addressing. Such redundant usages are removed from the comment when you submit it. For instance, if I tried adressing you at the start of this comment, it would be automatically removed.

Comment: Why do you want to mention the author of a post (question or answer) with @? When you write there, he'll know that you mean him (or her).

Comment: @Louis that makes sense, the [linked question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271527/username-disappears-in-comments) answered my question. But for example now, I bet this @ mention will render because the distinction between you and Tom is important.